# Pycaret setup train_size=1.0 parameter

Tags: installation, binary, classification, pycaret

Using pycaret setup() for only training , such that there is no test set data when searching for the best binary classification models.

Hi there,

Does anyone know if you can set the train_size=1.0 such that you want pycaret to perform only training to your input dataset and then use best to perform prediction on unseen data? At the moment I get errors when I set train_size =1.0

Thanks a lot for any input on this. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the train_size=1.0 if you want to train entire dataset you can do in 2 way

1. If you already have a testing dataset and want to train a model using the entire training dataset then you can supply testing dataset in the `test_data` parameter, when you specify `test_data` then `train_size` will be ignored.

```py
setup(data=training_dataset, test_data=testing_dataset, target = 'Purchase')
```

2. If you don't have a testing dataset then you need to split your dataset into training and testing datasets by specifying train_size. So you need to compare the model, analyze the model, and evaluate the model. Once you got the best model you can use the `finalize_model` method to trains a given estimator on the entire dataset including the holdout set.

```py
setup(data=dataset, train_size=0.7, target = 'Purchase')

best = compare_models()

# Finalize model
final_best = finalize_model(best)
```

You can find information about the method and parameters from [documentation](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classification.html#pycaret.classification.setup)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply. I have tried step 1, but it doesn't work for test_data which does not have the target column. I will try the step 2 which you recommended later and see how I get on.